# Output for loop to a file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to have a for loop output a text to a file 10 times. Here is what I have:

```
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do
    echo "Hello World" >testforloop.txt
done
```

This outputs `Hello World` once to the file `testforloop.txt`. If I don't output to file it prints `Hello World` to the screen 10 times.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using `>` redirection, which wipes out the existing contents of the file and replaces it with the command's output, inside the loop.  So this wipes out the previous contents 10 times, replacing it with one line each time.

Without the `>`, or with `>/dev/tty`, it goes to your display, where `>` cannot wipe anything out so you see all ten copies.

You could use `>>`, which will still open the file ten times, but will append (not wipe out previous contents) each time.  That's not terribly efficient though, and it retains data from a previous run (which may or may not be what you want).

Or, you can redirect the entire loop once:

```
for ... do cmd; done >file
```

which runs the entire loop with output redirected, creating (or, with `>>`, opening for append) only once.

Comment: Maybe also note that `... done >file` is more efficient (sometimes remarkably so) because you open, buffer, write, and close the file just once.

Comment: @tripleee: buffering and writing are internal to the command (unless it's a shell built-in).  Open is a relatively slow op though, so that's why this is "more efficient".  The main drawback—which does not apply here—is that *all* commands inside the loop have their output redirected, so if you only want some, you have to do something else.

Comment: But opening, writing, and closing a line at a time effectively disables any buffering, whereas a single redirection allows for buffering to take place, although perpaps not in this particular case.

Comment: @tripleee: actually, in this case it *is* a shell built-in.  I haven't dug into the innards of bash so I am not sure it helps much anyway (shells tend to have to do a lot of flushing and such, they're very hard to make both correct and efficient internally).

Answer (score 6):

You're only redirecting the echo with ">", so it overwrites. What you need is to append using ">>" operator. Do the following:

```
       for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)) ; do echo "Hello World" >> testforloop.txt ;  done
```

Comment: This is OK, but as @torek points out, writing once is better than appending many times.

Comment: @kojiro Yes, his point is right and efficient. But, questioner was having problem getting "redirection" and "append" right.

Comment: But it's not merely *appending* to the file 10 times. It's *opening the file for appending* 10 times. So I think it's still pretty important to point out the difference.

Comment: Look, I didn't disagree with torek's point, I also gave +1 for that, but you need to understand, when someone having problem getting ">" and ">>" right, certainly he's not thinking about making statement efficient, he's learning, so it's also *important* that he knows what ">" and ">>" are all about, after he's clear about the concept then he can go for making things efficient. I think you haven't learn efficient coding,  before learning programming ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**The following will solve your problem:**

You should try the `>>` operator for the reasons already mentioned with the command `echo -e`

> Using option ‘\n‘ – New line with backspace interpretor ‘-e‘ treats
>    new line from where it is used.

[link](https://www.tecmint.com/echo-command-in-linux/)

**Doing so:**

`for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)) ; do echo -e "Hello World" >> testforloop.txt ;  done`

**cat command:**

`cat testforloop.txt`

**output:**

`Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World`

**Alternatively, you can try:**

`cat -n testforloop.txt`

**output:**

`1  Hello World
 2  Hello World
 3  Hello World
 4  Hello World
 5  Hello World
 6  Hello World
 7  Hello World
 8  Hello World
 9  Hello World
 10  Hello World`

Answer (score -1):

You rewrite the testforloop.txt ten times. If you did

for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)) ; do echo "Hello World" > testforloop(i).txt ;  done

where i is the int from the for loop. I'm not sure the language you're programming in.

Comment: -1 He's programming in `bash`. This answer is also hard to understand because (syntax issues aside) it just seems to repeat the problem.